# Undefined index error using $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Tags: php

Debug is throwing...

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-content\themes\mytheme\header.php
>   on line 4

How can I change my function below to prevent the error?

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 }
```

Would this be the equivalent?

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] )) {$pageURL .= "s";}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Some servers simply don't set [`$_SERVER['HTTPS']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) if the request is non-secure. Some others may set it to `'off'`. You'll have to check it like this:

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) == "on" ) {
    $pageURL .= "s";
}
```

Comment: why you use strtolower?

Answer (score 4):

`Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS` says that `HTTPS` is not a key within the `$_SERVER` array. It doesn't exist, so you can't compare it with `"on"`.

`isset()` checks whether a variable is "set" or even available for reference in this case. This would be the best choice in your case.