# Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in

Tags: php

I Have an question: How to fixed error Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in.

This is line code:

```
public static function getCurrentURL() {
    $requri = !isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $protocol = strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]);
    $protocol = substr($protocol, 0, strpos($protocol, '/')) . ($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on'?'s':'');
    $port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '80' ? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port . $requri;
}
```

The line with error:

```
$protocol = substr($protocol, 0, strpos($protocol, '/')) . ($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on'?'s':'');
```

---

I Get this error Notice: Undefined index: UID in line 30:

```
$_UID = $_COOKIE['UID'] ? $_COOKIE['UID'] : 0;
```

And This error Notice: Undefined variable: G_UID in line 27:

```
if ($G_UID && $G_URL && $G_ADT) {
    $surl  = SITE_LOCATION;
    $db    = System::getDB();
    $user  = $G_UID;
```

If need, i post the code complete here.

Thank You.

Comment: are you sure that the protocol is HTTPS and not HTTP? cause in this case the index is not defined on the server

Comment: I change HTTPS for HTTP, But I Get both error.

Comment: the below answer which is stoled form here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911532/undefined-index-error-using-serverhttps will work

Comment: Regarding the edit: You need to learn how to fix and debug these things on your own. A StackOverflow question every time you get an `Undefined index` notice will not be sustainable. Look at how it was solved with `isset` and figure out how to apply that knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If HTTPS is off, `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` will not be defined, leading to that notice.

Change:

```
($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on'?'s':'')
```

to:

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on'?'s':'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$protocol = substr($protocol, 0, strpos($protocol, '/')) . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? ($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on'?'s':'' ): '');
```