# Undefined index: HTTPS in /XXX/index.php on line 35 at post

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

Undefined index: HTTPS in /XXX/index.php on line 35 at post.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
    $mydomain = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
} else {
    $mydomain = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

The code at line 35 are as follows;

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
```

Comment: check if it set before use try if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')

Comment: More a duplicate of [Undefined index error using $_SERVER['HTTPS'\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911532/undefined-index-error-using-serverhttps)

Comment: @Omi  Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: @DramaOnline please check you have closed isset bracket before &&

Answer (score 0):

check if the variable `$_SERVER` isset before checking the `$_SERVER` value

this line

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
```

should be as follows

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: sorry im using mobile, it was a typo in my code, i've fixed it

Comment: @DramaOnline https://3v4l.org/oOGTI