# Notice: Undefined index: HTTP not "HTTPS"

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP in /home/mysite/public_html/application/config/config.php on line 20

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTP'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
```

this is in my line no 20 of config.php file. What's wrong in this line?

[Undefined index error using $_SERVER['HTTPS']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911532/undefined-index-error-using-serverhttps)

is irrelevant with my question because my previous code was working fine and its ssl issue cause from october 2017 ssl is mandatory for http sites and the erro started from that time.

Comment: `HTTPS` != `HTTP`. Add the missing `S`.

Comment: where did I miss the s?

Comment: It should be `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on"`

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index error using $\_SERVER\['HTTPS'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911532/undefined-index-error-using-serverhttps)

Comment: By the way, mysite was working fine before this with $_SERVER['HTTP'] == "on" , why suddenly it started showing this error?

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911532/undefined-index-error-using-serverhttps> is not duplicate with my question because my site was working fine before with HTTP . this error is because - from October 2017 ssl certificate made mandatory in Cpanel. there is a warning notification about this in the Cpanel I just noticed few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line to

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
```

This part of the line is the problem. It should be `HTTPS` instead

```
$_SERVER['HTTP']
```